# Batch file closing for no apparent reason

Tags: batch-file

I enjoy coding, scripting and other stuff, and today my friend showed me how to make a batch file. I made one, so I run it. it works well, until I get to the one part, where it just closes.
It's supposed to go through the slides, it does that well. But when it gets to the part that it does `goto t1win` it just closes the .bat file.

Here is my code:

```
 @echo off
cls
:loop
:menu
echo hello
color 0a
color 0
cls
echo This is for scripture stuff.
set /p=
goto scrn1

:scrn2
cls
echo Whats your partner's name?
set /p p2=
goto scrn3

:scrn5
cls
echo Time for the questions!
set /p=
goto scrn6

:t1win
cls
echo Yay! %p1% and %p2%, you did it!
set /p=
exit

:scrn7
cls
echo 2.
echo.
echo %p2%, How did the barges have light? (a= The barges had windows b= Jesus touched stones and the stones gave off light c= The people used lanterns)
echo.
set /p t1q2=
if %q1t2% == a goto scrn7
if %q1t2% == b goto t1win
if %q1t2% == c goto scrn7

if not defined start (
cls
goto loop
)

:scrn4
cls
echo Open the book 'Book of Mormon Stories', to page #145. Read until page #148, but still read #148. Press enter when you are done reading.
set /p=
goto scrn5

:scrn6
cls
echo 1.
echo.
echo Hey %p1%! What did the brother of Jared build? (a=barges b=boats c=planes)
echo.
set /p t1q1=
if %t1q1% == a goto scrn7
if %t1q1% == b goto scrn6
if %t1q1% == c goto scrn6

:scrn1
cls
echo Whats your name?
set /p p1=
goto scrn2

:scrn3
cls
echo Hello, %p1% and %p2%!
set /p=
goto scrn4
```

Please help.
BTW I don't really care if it jumps around like the sample.
this is the first question I asked, so don't judge meh!

Comment: In `:scrn7`, you're setting input to the variable `tlq2`, but you're checking input with the variable `qlt2`. Since you never set `qlt2` anywhere, your code throws a syntax error. On an unrelated note, `pause` is much better for making the user press any key to continue.

Comment: @SomethingDark
ohhhh that's why. Oh, that's how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the code! :D

```
@echo off

cls
:menu
echo hello
color 0a
color 0
cls
echo This is for scripture stuff.
set /p=
goto scrn1

:scrn2
cls
echo Whats your partner's name?
set /p p2=
goto scrn3

:scrn5
cls
echo Time for the questions!
set /p=
goto scrn6

:t1win
cls
echo Yay! %p1% and %p2%, you did it!
set /p=
exit

:scrn7
cls
echo 2.
echo.
echo %p2%, How did the barges have light? (a= The barges had windows b= Jesus touched stones and the stones gave off light c= The people used lanterns)
echo.
set /p t1q2=
if %t1q2% == a goto scrn7
if %t1q2% == b goto t1win
if %t1q2% == c goto scrn7

if not defined start (
cls
goto loop
)

:scrn4
cls
echo Open the book 'Book of Mormon Stories', to page #145. Read until page #148, but still read #148. Press enter when you are done reading.
set /p=
goto scrn5

:scrn6
cls
echo 1.
echo.
echo Hey %p1%! What did the brother of Jared build? (a=barges b=boats c=planes)
echo.
set /p t1q1=
if %t1q1% == a goto scrn7
if %t1q1% == b goto scrn6
if %t1q1% == c goto scrn6

:scrn1
cls
echo Whats your name?
set /p p1=
goto scrn2

:scrn3
cls
echo Hello, %p1% and %p2%!
set /p=
goto scrn4
```

Comment: `set /p=
exit` 
Actually, that code makes it so that when you press enter it closes, I tried that in several other files and it worked.

Comment: Hi! try that format! instead of creating another line for exit! Best Wishes! :D

Comment: Nope, it still closes.

Comment: Hey! open it in CMD you can see where the error is! I tried copying your code to review but I think the problem is the _goto_ part...

Comment: How to open in cmd...?

Comment: hey! :D if you try opening it in CMD, some choices will end up saying; "goto was unexpected at this time." maybe it isn't the exit part it's more like the part where the program goes...

Comment: just hold shift then right-click and "select open command windows here"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222156/discussion-between-thecomputerwizard-and-fryron).